# can I run nextjs static app on 1.5GB ram linux cpanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cpanel

I am going to deploy nextjs app to shared hosting, which has 1.5GB ram but when I run the app "npm start" its giving me following error:

```
returncode: 0
stdout:
> frontend@0.1.0 start /home/myapp/strapi-frontend
> NODE_ENV=production node server.js

info  - Loaded env from /home/myapp/strapi-frontend/.env
stderr:
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/myapp/nodevenv/strapi-frontend/14/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
(node:7658) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
    at internal/deps/cjs-module-lexer/dist/lexer.js:1:33593
    at async initCJSParse (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:72:5)
    at async Loader.commonjsStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:185:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:67:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7658) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:7658) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
```

Can anyone tell me possible solutions how can fix this issue or is it not possible in this enviroment.

Comment: Have you tried running it locally with `npm run start`, to see if the error persists? I can't see any hint right now, that would indicate a memory problem.

Comment: Locally it working fine

Comment: oh, I missed the "shared" part. That would mean, you've got less then 1.5 gigs available.

Comment: Try the following. Deploy a fresh nextjs app, wiuthout any customizsations to your shared instance. Just make sure that the next / node versions are the same. If the errors is no longer there, slowly start adding functionality back in until it happens. If there is a memory leak, this might lead you to it

Comment: its productioin ready how can I start from scratch

Comment: Create an empty app with `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` and deploy that.

Comment: I deployed fresh project but same error accurs